# Is there some way that I can pass the return value of one helper function into another as a parameter in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I have run into a problem with a current project using Handlebars.js. I am writing a complex template which must be output only as text (it is fed directly as a string to a text printer) and that text can be a maximum of 40 chars wide.

The problem I have is that I need to use various helper functions to get and organise my data, but I then need to take that text and put it though another function to format it into the 40 char width.

So... I have helper functions that look a bit like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getLit' , function (litName) {
    // some logic to retrieve a string lit in correct language
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('getArrayValue', function(array, key) {
    return array[key];
});

Handlebars.registerHelper('textFormat', function(string, max_width, align) {
    // logic to format the text
});
```

Now if my htm looks like this:

```
{{textFormat "This is a really long string that needs formating into the correcct length blah blah blah blah" 40 'left'}}
```

I have no problems.

However I need to be able to use helper function to build the string e.g.

```
{{textFormat {{getArrayValue address 0}} 40 'right'}}
```

I hope my explanation is not too convoluted, obviously the data I am dealing with is very large and very complex  so simply preparing all the data to feed into the template (e.g. instead of using getLit making 6 forms of each string in their various languages) is just not practical.

Is there anyway to make this work or do I need to use a totally different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use nested helpers. If you need include new helper, use construct

```
{{#textformat 10 'right'}}
  {{getArrayValue address 0}}
{{/textformat}}
```

You can find out more about constructing block helpers here: http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html